# Kettle - Truncated file name after Zip File Step

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm using a Job (that calls some transformations) to import some text file into a MS SQL table.
After the transformation, I want to zip the imported files, so I added a Zip File Step at the end of my job.
So far so good. The problem is that the file name inside the zip archive got truncated. The first letter of the files is missing.
Original file name is like "PUB_MZ_BAX0_......".
Inside the zip archive: "UB_MZ_BAX0_....".

How can I fix that??

Comment: Can You add the xml of the ktr and necessary data so that I can reproduce it in my machine.

Comment: As suggested, it would be very helpful to see the XML scope of the zip step, anything between the relevant scope of `<step>` and `</step>`

Comment: Sorry for not answering your comments, but time is runnung short here. I changed my version of JRE installed on the machine running the job (because of some problems with another application), and then the problem seems solved. I was using a JRE 8 (64 bits) and now it's running in a JRE 7 (32 bits). Can someone flag this question as closed??